# Filling comboBox from SQLite database in PyQt

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm trying to fill comboBox from SQLite database, but nothing is pulled up.

My code

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
import sqlite3
from test_rt_sql import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.model = QSqlTableModel()
    self.model.setTable('user')
    self.model.select()
    self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)
    self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_val)

    self.show()

def comboBox_val(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/sqlite/test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
    rows = c.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(row)

    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I tried to return a list to it in `addItems`, I got an error

```
self.ui.comboBox.addItems(self.comboBox_val)
TypeError: addItems(self, texts: Iterable[Optional[str]]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'method'
```

As I understand it, it does not like the argument `addItems` , that there is not specifically referring to the data, but to the method.

The code where the list was returned:

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
import sqlite3
from test_rt_sql import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('user')
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(self.comboBox_val)

        self.show()

    def comboBox_val(self):
        global data1
        conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/sqlite/test.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
        data1 = []

        for row in c.fetchall():
            data1.append(str(row))

        return data1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec()
```

The database is definitely connected and the data is given. I checked it like this.

```
import sqlite3

def comboBox_val():
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/sqlite/test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

comboBox_val()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5xO9.png)

Comment: You either properly use the QSqlTableModel (by correctly connecting to the database) or you use `addItem()` with the default combobox model. You cannot do *both*.

Comment: (1) open a database connection *before* creating the model: `db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE'); db.setDatabaseName('C:/sqlite/test.db'); db.open()`; (2) set the correct column in the combo-box: `self.comboBox.setModelColumn(self.model.fieldIndex('user'))`; (3) remove all the sqlite3 stuff, which is not needed; (4) **most importantly**: do yourself a favour, and read [a basic tutorial on using SQL databases in PyQt](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-database/).

Answer (score 0):

I initially turned to the wrong place.

Connect to the base `create_connection` , and then already `QSqlTableModel` , the query itself specified in `setQuery`

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase
from test_rt_sql import Ui_MainWindow

def create_connection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/sqlite/test.db")
    return True

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    create_connection()

    self.model = QSqlTableModel()
    self.model.setTable('user')
    self.model.setQuery('SELECT name FROM user')
    self.model.select()
    self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)

    self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```